# Symfony config | trusted hosts | Correct regex pattern for any subdomain?

Tags: regex, symfony, configuration

I'm working on my first Symfony-based application and I want to use the "trusted_hosts" option to make my app a little more secure. I started developing by using Symfony's own HTTP server which ran under "localhost". But I also have an Apache with correct vHosts setup for www.*domain* & dev.*domain*. I was developing over dev.*domain* before switching to Symfony.

Now I want to add a wildcard for any sub-domain to the trusted hosts and I follow the advertised pattern [at the Symfony config docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#trusted-hosts) but somehow it doesn't get recognized and I get an "Untrusted host" error on a nice symfony-generated error page.

Please tell me, what's wrong in my regex pattern, that's what I have in my framework.yaml:

```
trusted_hosts: ['localhost', '^(.+\.)?my-domain$']
```

I know a little about regex patterns and can't see any fault here. Or maybe I'm just blind. Any help would be appreciated, I'm sure as soon somebody points out the error, I will slap myself for being so blind, haha... Thank you!

Comment: If it is PHP based, you need to use regex delimiters, and `'^(.+\.)?my-domain$'` will turn into something like `'~^(.+\.)?my-domain$~'`, and `'localhost'` to `'/localhost/'` (or again, `'~localhost~'`)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thank you for help! I got it working already, seems like my automatic file uploads to server were not working correctly, after updating the file manually it worked! :)

Comment: It is a good idea to post what you did to make it work as an answer.

Comment: As I said: my project files were not in sync with the test deployment directory, it basically wasn't a technical fault but a configuration error in PHP Storm from my side. So there is no solution to no real problem. Thanks again anyway!